# Pass extra data as a variable from controller to API Resource (Collection Resource) in Laravel

Tags: laravel-9

i'm trying to pass a variable that has region name as a string from a json file from controller to API resource but, instead of getting region name for example "Riyadh Region" i'm getting "0" I dont know why. Here is my code [[API resource code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU5lq.png)]
[[Post controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kGgl.png)]

Here is my output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tuvy.png)

i'm getting region name as 0 and 1 instead of Riyadh Region why?

Comment: Hi, please avoid screenshots of code. Read docs here [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't pass an additional variable to the resource that way.
Method `collection` receives only one parameter:

```
 /**
 * Create a new anonymous resource collection.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $resource
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection
 */
public static function collection($resource)
{
    return tap(new AnonymousResourceCollection($resource, static::class), function ($collection) {
        if (property_exists(static::class, 'preserveKeys')) {
            $collection->preserveKeys = (new static([]))->preserveKeys === true;
        }
    });
}
```

To pass a variable set a **static property** of your resource instead:

`PostController.php`:

```
PostResource::$regionName = $regionRequest['name_en'];

return PostResource::collection ($post);
```

`PostResource.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource{
    public static $regionName;

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->post,
            'region_name' => $this->when(isset($this->regionName), self::$regionName)
        ];
    }
}
```